# Local variable inside mysql statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use a local varaible inside a mysql statement.

I've a statement that looks something like this (unrelated fields, joins and conditions have been filtered):

```
SELECT
  m.id,
  IF (!m.subscribers_only OR m.user_id = ? OR !ISNULL(mu.media_id) OR !ISNULL(us.user_id), 1, 0) AS has_access
FROM media m
LEFT JOIN media_user mu ON mu.user_id = ? AND m.id = mu.media_id
LEFT JOIN user_subscriptions us ON us.user_id = ? AND m.user_id = us.user_subscriber_to_id
```

All 3 variable is the same variable, so instead of having to bind the parameter 3 times, is it possible to set a local variable in the statement and only having to do 1 bind.

I've considered using `SET @current_user = 1` and then using `@current_user`, but as I'm using PDO, it's not possible to run two statements in one query, and I'm worried how the interaction is when combined with a load balancer.

Edit to show how I'm printing @paramter_test:

```
SELECT
  m.id,
  @parameter_test,
  IF (!m.subscribers_only OR m.user_id = @parameter_test OR !ISNULL(mu.media_id) OR !ISNULL(us.user_id), 1, 0) AS has_access
  FROM media m
JOIN (SELECT @parameter_test:= 1) a
LEFT JOIN media_user mu ON mu.user_id = @parameter_test AND m.id = mu.media_id
LEFT JOIN user_subscriptions us ON us.user_id = @parameter_test AND m.user_id = us.user_subscriber_to_id
```

Comment: `!m.subscribers` - what does that do?

Comment: m.subscribers is a tinyint field, so that will return true or false

Comment: well one part seems to be `us.user_id = mu.user_id` so that removes one repetition, similarly if that's true then `mu.user_id = m.user_id` removes a second repetition as well?

Comment: I considered that aswell but it does not work as mu.user_id is in a left join and will be null, if the left join is unsuccesful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT
m.id,
IF (!m.subscribers_only OR m.user_id = @parameter_test OR !ISNULL(mu.media_id) OR 
!ISNULL(us.user_id), 1, 0) AS has_access
FROM media m
JOIN (SELECT @parameter_test:= 1) a
LEFT JOIN media_user mu ON mu.user_id = @parameter_test AND m.id = mu.media_id
LEFT JOIN user_subscriptions us ON us.user_id = @parameter_test AND m.user_id = 
us.user_subscriber_to_id
```

You can always create a variable inside a sql statement as long as it's declared before it's use.

In this case you won't be using placeholder ? since those are replaced by parameter.

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain where the placeholder `?` would go to set the value of the local variable

Comment: This seems to work for the two parameters in the LEFT JOINS, but if I try to print the parameter in the IF, the value is NULL there.

I tried to set it as the first value in the SELECT, but it's still not available in the IF

Comment: Could you give an example of how are you printing it? the parameter should be available in the select section as well.

Comment: I was wrong. I didn't use := but only a =. Changing it made it work. Thank you